# PHP need to set size of File

Tags: php, file, size

How I can set current size of file?

In my code I do firstly `fopen( $inPath, "r+" );`.
Secondly do `fwrite($mFile, $mPage, $kLicenceSize);`.

`$mFile` -> The file I opened,

`$mPage` -> data that I should write to the file,

`$kLicenceSize` -> 4096 (4 KB).

As a result, I should get a 4KB file that contains the data that was mentioned earlier. Btw data can be < 4KB.

Comment: Literally no idea what you are actually trying to ask us. Please have a go at making the question understandable. If English is your issue, use Google translate, ask the question in your own language and then show us the English conversion

Comment: You have still not told us what the problem is

Comment: And please show us the real code, we are developers, we understand code

Comment: `As a result, I should get`...ok, and what do you actually get? What is the issue?

Comment: FROM THE `fwrite()` MANUAL `If the length argument is given, writing will stop after length bytes have been written or the end of string is reached, **whichever comes first**.` So it will stop after `mPage` number of bytes, it wont invent bytes to pack the file out to 4k

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I know it. My problem is "How can I create a 4K file even if the data is smaller?"

Comment: You make the `$mPage` variable that size, if necessary pad it out with spaces or something

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok, I'll try to do that

Answer (score 2):

That isn't how `fwrite()` works. From the doc: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

> length
>
> ```
> If the length argument is given, writing will stop after length bytes have been written or the end of string is reached, whichever comes first.
> ```

By including a *length* parameter in your `fwrite()` call, you are ensuring that the file that is written is never above your *length* (4kb), you are not setting the size of the file to *length*

**Edit based on comments**
You could use `str_pad()`:

```
$paddedFile = str_pad( $mFile, $kLicenceSize );
fwrite($paddedFile, $mPage, $kLicenceSize);
```

Comment: Yes, I know it. My problem is "How can I create a 4K file even if the data is smaller?"

Comment: You would have to determine the length of your data, then pad the data to meet the required length. What is the use case?

Comment: @Rostislav `How can I create a 4K file even if the data is smaller?`...what would be the point of that, apart from wasting disk space?

Comment: @ADyson I just create a project that first generates a 4Kb file with serial key data. Then this file is encrypted and sent to the buyer. This is the purpose of this program

Comment: @Rostislav sure, but why must it be 4KB exactly? Why not smaller?

Comment: @ADyson The application for which the file is created requires 4Kb